# OpenCV Simple Blob Detection - displaying results in a window

Tags: python, opencv, blob, raspberry-pi2

```
Setup:<br>
Raspberry Pi 2<br>
Debian 7.8 Wheezy<br>
OpenCV 2.4.1<br>
Raspberry Pi camera module<br>
```

I am trying to get the results of simple blob detection to show up in an image window with the blobs circled.  I have verified that keypoint detection is working because I've run:
print keypoints
and I can see a varying number of keypoints printed to the command line as I point the camera around the room.

Testing further, holding a white piece of paper with a single black circle drawn on it in front of the camera reduces the number of keypoints printed to the command line to one.  Holding a white piece of paper with nothing drawn on it produces zero keypoints. Perfect! So, the detection of default keypoints (simple black circles) appears to be working just fine.

Now the challenge:

How do I get those keypoints to show up on an image that I can see on my screen?

When I try to run the program, it chokes when I add this line of code:

```
output_image = cv2.drawKeypoints(input_image, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
```

The error message is:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'drawKeypoints'

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: How did you make those edits?  It reads much nicer that way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
1. Upgrade the Raspberry PI operating system to Jessie
2. sudo apt-get update  (this should be standard practice!)
3. sudo apt-get upgrade  (this should be standard practice!)
4. sudo rpi-update  (this should be standard practice!)
5. sudo apt-get install python-opencv
6. sudo apt-get install libg1l-mesa-dri
7. Copy the program and related files to the new memory card
 
8. Run the blob detection program!

Step 6 was needed to prevent the following error:
"Window system doesn't support OpenGL"

I can't believe this worked!